# Копирование файла с прогрессом

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Какие лучшие практики сейчас применяются для копирования большого файла с прогрессом в UI-приложениях? Меня интересуют не компоненты на форме, а сам процесс копирования. Требования следующие:

1. снизить бездумное расходование ресурсов впустую
2. копирование не должно блокировать главный UI поток
3. на форме должен отображаться прогресс копирования

Нашел `FileStream.CopyToAsync`, но с его помощью, вроде как, не отобразить прогресс. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Копировать вручную поблочно, через ReadAsync/WriteAsync?

Comment: класс `BackgroundWorker` вот ссылка на пример http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/documents_WPF/level31/31_3.php

Comment: @VladD, ну тут не совсем ясно  какой брать блок, да и см.1 пункт: каждый await несет за собой немалые накладные расходы. Просто так пробовал, и если брать блок по 1024 - нагрузка на цп была куда выше, чем через синхронные методы. Понятно, что 1024 - это мало, поэтому и спрашиваю: "лучшие практики, которые сейчас применяются"

Comment: @S.Kost, зачем, когда есть `async\await`? Он выполняет ту же функциональность, но красивее. Вопрос не в том "как это можно сделать", вопрос в первом предложении: "Какие лучшие практики сейчас применяются для копирования большого файла с прогрессом в UI-приложениях?"

Comment: [The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) by Stephen Toub - бесплатная книга по асинхронности от гуру дотнета. В конце приводятся разнообразные примеры асинхронного копирования, в том числе с прогрессом.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570934/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-io-%D0%B2-c/571233#571233

Comment: Кратко: 1024 байта - это четверть размера страницы. Это - означает, что те данные, которые ОС загружает с иска за раз - вы читаете в 4 этапа. Разумеется, это медленно! Читать надо не менее десятка страниц за раз.