# Буферизация при IO в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, в чем смысл буферизации при чтении и записи?

Почему нельзя читая сразу писать?

Например, нужно скопировать файл из пункта А в пункт Б.

Сначала мы считываем байты в буфер, а потом из этого буфера начинаем запись.

Так как буфер является настраиваемым параметрам, то когда следует использовать большой буфер, а когда маленький и какой в этом получается профит.

Например, в некоторых исходниках .NET классов явным образам пробиты константы размера буфера.

Comment: потому что для каждого байта головка диска будет прыгать туда сюда и вы получите никакую скорость. Чем больше буфер, тем менее часто головка будет перемещаться. Чем больше буфер - тем более он скушает памяти при копировании.

Comment: @vitidev: Нууу, у ОС есть своя буферизация. И у современных дисков тоже.

Comment: @VladD Я начал с основ. Впрочем на наличие буферов у ОС и HDD можно не обращать внимания.

Comment: Не стоит отмечать вопросы меткой [tag:microsoft]. Она не добавляет смысла, т.к. слишком общая.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно ознакомиться с этим материалом: [Sequential File Programming Patterns and Performance with .NET](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/sequential-file-programming-patterns-and-performance-with-net/). Написана статья в 2004, но обновление сделано в 2010 (судя по датам в тексте).

Приведу выдержку (вольный перевод мой):

1. Для одного диска используйте настройки по умолчанию фреймворка .NET - они предоставляют отличную производительность для последовательного доступа к файлу.
2. Предварительно выделяйте место для больших файлов (используя `SetLength()` method), когда создаете файл. Это обычно улучшает скорость примерно на 13% в сравнении с фрагментированным файлом.
3. По крайней мере, сейчас, дисковые массивы требуют небуферизованный IO для достижения лучшей производительности. Буферизованный IO может быть в 8 раз медленнее, чем небуферизованный. Мы ожидаем, что эта проблема будет рассмотрена в более поздних выпусках .NET-фреймворка.
4. Если вы делаете свою собственную буферизацию, используйте большие размеры буфера (64 Кб хорошая отправная точка).
5. Используя .NET-фреймворк, один процессор может читать и писать дисковый массив на скорости свыше 800 Мб*сек, используя небуферизованный IO.

Самым интересным в этом списке является пункт 3: при копировании данных с одного **физического** диска на другой **физический** буферизация вредна (естественно, буферизация на уровне драйвера диска остается). В остальных случаях она, по крайней мере, не вредит.

---

Подумав, решил добавить, что [BufferedStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream(v=vs.110).aspx), применяемый поверх `NetworkStream` фактически хоть и буферизует данные при передаче между физическими устройствами, в данном случае скорее всего будет эффективен, за счёт уменьшения количества пакетов.

Answer (score 2):

в дополнение к ответу vitidev:
Чтение с диска и запись производится блоками по несколько килобайт и операция эта очень медленная относительно работы с оперативной памятью. Если писать очень маленькими блоками - получаем низкую производительность, если слишком большими - большой расход оперативной памяти. Поэтому разработчики подбирают оптимальный размер буфера под конкретный случай.