# Эффективный алгоритм для асинхронного копирования папки

Tags: c#, многопоточность, распараллеливание, файловый-ввод-вывод

Часть моего проекта отвечает за копирование каталогов из одного места в другое. Сначала рекурсивно получаю список файлов в папке (отбрасывая файлы с исключениями), затем с этим списком работаю.
Проблема состоит в производительности. Копировать файлы по одному неэффективно. Однако, если для каждого выделить поток (или Task), это тоже плохое решение, потому что:

1. Количество и размер файлов могут быть разными.
2. Если чтение/запись происходит в пределах одного ЖЕСТКОГО диска, то при слишком частом обращении в разные каталоги он будет физически не успевать и производительность уменьшится...
3. Если при копировании одного из файлов возникает исключение, то программа жестко зависает на несколько секунд (проверял)

Нужен особый алгоритм, который будет совмещать синхронность и асинхронность. Например, находить какую-то зависимость между количеством и размером файлов, делить их на группы и др.

Наставьте меня на правильное решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно, будет полезно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571233/184217

Comment: Копировать в несколько потоков - плохая затея, и название этой затеи - фрагментация скопированных файлов. Для SSD это особо пофигу, но вот для HDD фрагментация это довольно плохо(да и собственно сама процедура доступа в несколько потоков)

Comment: @ГеннадийП - про фрагментацию, в целом, дельное замечание. Но ведь можно сразу выделить место на  диске для всего файла, ещё до копирования.

Comment: Очень полезная информация про фрагментацию, спасибо!
А что, если разбивать копирование на шаги? Это скажется на фрагментации диска и скорости, например, если на каждом шагу будет копироваться по 3-5 файлов легких файлов параллельно, а тяжелые в конце по очереди?
И стоит ли заморачиваться, чтобы узнать тип хранилища (SSD, HDD) и в зависимости от этого по-разному действовать?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не спорю, можно выделить. Но у HDD очень снижается скорость работы если читать/записывать в несколько потоков, а максимальная скорость достигается при линейном доступе. Оно и понятно: лишние перемещения головок сильно тормозят работу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1. Тупой.**

1. Создать общую очередь файлов для копирования, используя `ConcurrentQueue` и общий `CancellationToken`.
2. Создать N потоков для копирования файлов через `Task.Run()` с тем самым `CancellationToken`. Потоки забирают задание из очереди и копируют файл за файлом. Как только очедерь пуста и `IsCancellationRequested=true`, завершаем поток.
3. Создать поток, который обходит папку и наполняет очередь. Как только все файлы найдены, выставляем `IsCancellationRequested=true`.

**Вариант 2. Лучше.**

Получаем список файлов в IEnumerable и используем `Parallell.ForEach()`. Ну или через LINQ: `someList.AsParallel().ForEach((filePath)=> {...copy...}))`.

.NET TPL попытается подобрать оптимальное количество потоков автоматически.

**Вариант 3. Reactive. Модно и современно.**

Использовать observer pattern через The Reactive Extensions for .NET https://github.com/dotnet/reactive

Делить на группы вручную по размеру не имеет смысла, а вот подбирать количество потоков, чтобы не убить IO и не поставить жёсткие диски на колени -- имеет.

Comment: Запускать `Task.Run` для копирования файла - бессмысленно и расточительно. Поток будет стоять на выполнении IO. Кто такое плюсует? Следует использовать [Stream.CopyToAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1). В итоге можно запускать сколько угодно задач копирования, не потребляя потоки ОС.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не одного же файла. Каждый такой поток забирает задания из очереди и копирует файл за файлом, пока есть что копировать. `CopyToAsync` хорош для десятка файлов, но если их больше, то на НЖМД будет слишком много операций случайного доступа.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev Пробовал вариант 2. При большом количестве файлов программа не справляется, тормозит. Правда, чуть меньше нагрузка на диск, чем она была при Task.Run.

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз: `Task.Run` запускает CPU-bound поток. `Parallel.ForEach` и `AsParallel().ForEach` аналогично используют CPU-bound потоки. А копирование файлов - это IO-bound операции. В одном потоке ОС можно запускать сколько угодно IO-операций. Ваши варианты вредительские. Они, конечно, работают, но зря потребляют потоки.

Comment: @Юрик - _чуть меньше нагрузка на диск_ - это как раз-таки плохо. Если мы копируем файлы - то носитель должен быть загружен полностью - это показатель его максимальной отдачи. А вот процессор должен отдыхать при этом.

Answer (score -1):

Зависит от способа копирования, но в большинстве случаев наоборот эффективнее копировать по одному. А вот шаг составления списка файлов мне кажется лишним. Нашли файл, копируем.